# String interpolation, escaping quotation mark

Tags: scala, string-interpolation

I'm somewhat baffled by how difficult this turns out to be. I've already looked around stackoverflow, but no solution seems to work fine for me.

What I want to do:

```
val file = checkcache(fileName)

file match
{
    case Some(_) => {println(s"File $file found!"); file.get}
    case None => createFile(fileName)
}
```

Now, this works perfectly fine, for a file named "blubb" that already resides in the cache it outprints

> File blubb found

and returns the file.

Now I want this to be

> File "blubb" found

So I tried doing this:

```
case Some(_) => { println(s"File \" $file \" found!"); file.get}
```

Compiler throws

> ')' expected but string literal found.

Why is that and how do I escape a double quotation mark correctly and preferably without an empty space after or before the $file-variable?

Comment: There's an issue https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6476 and PR https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/4308 so maybe in our lifetime.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use triple quotation mark:

```
scala> s"""File "$file" found!"""
res0: String = File "blubb" found!
```