# Escape quotes in string interpolation s"ALTER TABLE ${keyspace}.\"${tableName}\""

Tags: scala, string-formatting, string-interpolation

In Scala, while querying Cassandra, this string interpolation

```
s"ALTER TABLE ${keyspace}.\"${tableName}\" "
```

gives me this error:

> error: value $ is not a member of String [INFO]           val
>   query:String=s"ALTER TABLE ${keyspace}.\"${tableName}\" ADD $colName
>   $dataTypeAsString;"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6476

Comment: typo in SO sorry

Comment: It seems that finding the actual Scala issue is easier than finding a duplicate on SO in this case? Maybe I'm searching the wrong keywords. How about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31366563/string-interpolation-escaping-quotation-mark/31366588)?

Comment: Thanks, that does seem to be the same answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\"` [does not work inside string interpolations](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6476).

Try using strings delimited by triple quotes:

```
s"""ALTER TABLE ${keyspace}."${tableName}" """
```

or escape the inner double quotes by additional `${...}`:

```
s"ALTER TABLE ${keyspace}.${'"'}${tableName}${'"'} "
```