# Scala string interpolation error

Tags: scala

I have a simple piece of code as follows:

`val k = '1'
val v = '2'
print(s"$k=\"$v\"")`

I meant the output is 1="2",but the above code doesn't work,complains `error: ')' expected but string literal found.`

Comment: ...or, alternatively, [escape double quotes as `${'"'}` instead of `\"`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49987671/escape-quotes-in-string-interpolation-salter-table-keyspace-tablename?noredirect=1&lq=1) (useful if you also have line breaks in the string).

Comment: Thanks  @AndreyTyukin for pointing out these 2 working ways.